# Mathematica output re-direction to certain screen

Tags: redirect, wolfram-mathematica, output

I need send calculated image onto screen connected to HDMI output.
How to organize the redirection of output of Mathematica drawing functions to certain computer display?

As I understand, the DisplayFunction settings define where appear my result. Which parameters I have to set for output stream in this case?

P.S. I use Math-9 at Windows 8.

Comment: You could post this question here for getting more answers http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to position a window then the UltraMon

https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/

utility with appropriate arguments can reposition the currently active window onto any desired monitor and this might accomplish what you are asking for.

Or if you can already manage creating and positioning the window yourself and what you are asking is how do you put results from one Mathematica window into into a different window then you might buy or borrow a copy of "An Introduction to Programming with Mathematica" by Wellin, Gaylord and Kamin 3rd or later edition which has chapter 10 describing "front end programming" and all the details needed for sending control and information from one Mathematica window to another. It would be possible to show you a tiny example, but that would likely need more information from you and the example would become more and more complicated and still not have enough for you that the book chapter would much better explain. Looking up NoteBookWrite in the help system might let you decide whether this seems promising for you.

Comment: I need set the result of a calculations as a full-screen image at second display. So any solutions for window-based output are not appropriate..

But it could be good as temporary palliative solution. 
Thanks, Bill!!
Any way, if somebody know how to organize true re-direction of graphics to certain display, let's explain me, please!